# Как правильнее по бэму?

Tags: html, css

Как будет правильно сделать по бэму элемент элемента правильнее?
.list
.list__item
.list__item-title
или
.list
.list__item item-list
.item-list__title

Comment: А что это вы написали? Css-селектор?

Comment: это типо названия класов хтмл

Comment: По БЭМ-у не бывает элемента элемента. https://ru.bem.info/methodology/faq/#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-block__elem1__elem2

Answer (score 4):

Бэм расшифровывается как: block__element--modificator.
В качестве модификатора, например, может использоваться позиционирование элемента: --sticky или размер: --big и т.д.

Правильно: .list__item .list-item .list-item__title